# Can I Remove the WebForms Script Tags from My ASP .NET MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<div class="firstColumn">
<% for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < Model.TaskAttributes.Count; rowCount += 2)
   {%>
       <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount]) %>
 <%}
%>
</div>
```

So, I have this bit of code which works fine, but I'm unhappy with all the MVC mark-up.

The solution does not support Razor syntax yet, so I'm stuck with this syntax, but I'm wondering if it can be cleaned up at all.

What I was thinking should work is this:

```
<div class="firstColumn">
<% for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < Model.TaskAttributes.Count; rowCount += 2)
   {
       Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount]);
   }
%>
</div>
```

This does not render any EditorFor's to my page, though. It appears that the '<%=' before the editorFor is cruicial. Is there any way to express this without having to close and open tags?

Comment: even if that code works, it s not a good code. it shouldnt have been doing that in your view.

Comment: I am aware of this. I have inherited technical debt and do not have the time scheduled to rewrite and propagate the changes everywhere, but if a small clean-up is possible then I would take that.

Comment: You could try `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount]);`.

Comment: <%= is shortcut for Response.Write() . Have you tried that?

Comment: @MikeSW if you submit your comment as an answer I will accept it. This worked.

Comment: @SeanAnderson You need to be **very, very careful** when using `Response.Write`. This is a raw dump of information into the response stream. You lose all validation and safety of the output and take total responsibility for it. I don't know that's worth losing a couple WebForms tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<%= is shortcut for Response.Write() . Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

That's really about as good as it's going to get. You need to have:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount]) %>
```

...so that the output is emitted to the response stream.  Even with MVC3 syntax you would have to write:

```
@for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < Model.TaskAttributes.Count; rowCount += 2) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount])
}
```

and not just:

```
@for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < Model.TaskAttributes.Count; rowCount += 2) {
    Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="firstColumn">
    @for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < Model.TaskAttributes.Count; rowCount += 2)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskAttributes[rowCount])
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This is a valid MVC3 conversion, but the OP has mentioned that Razor syntax is not available to him.  He's just trying to refactor some of the seemingly extraneous script tags.